# Clang-Tidy : readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements value has no effect

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

While running clang-tidy on an example code provided at https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/function-cognitive-complexity.html (`function3` in the examples).

with the below command

```
clang-tidy.exe Example.cpp -config="{Checks: '-*,readability-*',CheckOptions: [{key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.Threshold, value: 2},{key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements, value: false} ]}"
```

I get below output.

```
\Example.cpp:2:5: warning: function 'function3' has cognitive complexity of 3 (threshold 2) [readability-function-cognitive-complexity]
int function3(bool var1, bool var2) {
    ^
\Example.cpp:3:3: note: +1, including nesting penalty of 0, nesting level increased to 1
  if(var1) { // +1, nesting level +1
  ^
\Example.cpp:4:5: note: +2, including nesting penalty of 1, nesting level increased to 2
    if(var2)  // +2 (1 + current nesting level of 1), nesting level +1
    ^
\Example.cpp:4:13: warning: statement should be inside braces [readability-braces-around-statements]
    if(var2)  // +2 (1 + current nesting level of 1), nesting level +1
            ^
             {
\Example.cpp:5:14: warning: 42 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
      return 42;
```

So, it seems that the key `readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements` has no effect. I also tried with

```
{key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements, value: 'false'}`
{key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements, value: '0'}
{key: readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements, value: 0}
```

but still got the additional diagnostics on the lines that increase cognitive complexity.
So, I think readability-function-cognitive-complexity.DescribeBasicIncrements is broken or am I doing something wrong?

Additional info:

- clang version 12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source of your problem:

> Additional info:
>
> - clang version 12.0

`DescribeBasicIncrements` option was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/bff7faea2034abed4535645d7c771e67c1f2bb23) which was not part of clang 12.0

Install the latest clang version and it should work as intended.